# How do I get values from a single Firebase Datasnapshot

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Datasnapshot. How do I get the values

```
{-KjmlcYIQzSIx__wHbSL=
{driverEmail=nyagakaenock@gmail.com,
 dateExpected=2017/05/16 14:00 PM,
 status=P,
 dateCompleted=, 
travelTime=8.5 HRS, 
loginTime=, 
active=Y,
 locationCompletedLocation=,
 vehicleChecks=,
 receivedInstructions=}
}
```

Comment: From which programming language / platform are you trying to access this data snapshot?

Comment: To get your going, please review [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will help you formulate your question, and show what you have tried. Then see the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) which covers how to read data from Firebase. Then *write some code* and post it when you get stuck and we'll try to help!

Comment: For Web / Javascript. calling [datasnapshot.val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val) will return the JSON object, while calling [datasnapshot.key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) to get the key, which in your example is `-KjmlcYIQzSIx__wHbSL`